# c# Linq query to group items by group and then sub-group

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, group-by, subquery

Question : I have a list of items which I need to first group and then sub group by the number of items in their product group. Code below. The objective is to create matching groups where the zones and the products available in each match. The zone and product are subject to change, but the number products available should always be grouped.

for example. given the below...

Result should be...

```
Group 1
Zone = "EAST", Product = "Bananas", ShippingTime = "3_Days" };
Zone = "EAST", Product = "Oranges", ShippingTime = "5_Days" };
Zone = "SOUTH", Product = "Bananas", ShippingTime = "3_Days" };
Zone = "SOUTH", Product = "Oranges", ShippingTime = "10_Days" };
```

Group 2

```
Zone = "WEST", Product = "Oranges", ShippingTime = "3_Days" };
Zone = "WEST", Product = "Oranges", ShippingTime = "5_Days" };
Zone = "WEST", Product = "Oranges", ShippingTime = "10_Days" };
Zone = "WEST", Product = "Apples", ShippingTime = "3_Days" };
Zone = "WEST", Product = "Apples", ShippingTime = "5_Days" };
Zone = "WEST", Product = "Apples", ShippingTime = "5_Days" };
Zone = "WEST", Product = "Bananas", ShippingTime = "3_Days" };
Zone = "WEST", Product = "Bananas", ShippingTime = "5_Days" };
Zone = "WEST", Product = "Bananas", ShippingTime = "5_Days" };
```

The ideal grouping would be to break out the below from Group 2 (caus' they match what's in group 1) and add to 
group 1, thus leaving the residual in group 2.

```
Zone = "WEST", Product = "Bananas", ShippingTime = "3_Days" };
Zone = "WEST", Product = "Oranges", ShippingTime = "10_Days" };
```

Here's the test I've been working with. Nothing I've been able to do with linq seems to get the job  done.
Thanks in Advance for the ideas.

```
public void should_group_products_and_shippingtimes()
        {
            {
                Bananas = "Limited DR";
                var a = new MyClass { Id = 1, Zone = "EAST", Product = "Bananas", ShippingTime = "3_Days" };
                var b = new MyClass { Id = 2, Zone = "EAST", Product = "Oranges", ShippingTime = "5_Days" };
                var c = new MyClass { Id = 3, Zone = "SOUTH", Product = "Bananas", ShippingTime = "3_Days" };
                var d = new MyClass { Id = 4, Zone = "SOUTH", Product = "Oranges", ShippingTime = "10_Days" };
                var e = new MyClass { Id = 5, Zone = "WEST", Product = "Oranges", ShippingTime = "3_Days" };
                var f = new MyClass { Id = 6, Zone = "WEST", Product = "Oranges", ShippingTime = "5_Days" };
                var g = new MyClass { Id = 7, Zone = "WEST", Product = "Oranges", ShippingTime = "10_Days" };
                var h = new MyClass { Id = 8, Zone = "WEST", Product = "Apples", ShippingTime = "3_Days" };
                var i = new MyClass { Id = 9, Zone = "WEST", Product = "Apples", ShippingTime = "5_Days" };
                var j = new MyClass { Id = 10, Zone = "WEST", Product = "Apples", ShippingTime = "5_Days" };
                var k = new MyClass { Id = 11, Zone = "WEST", Product = "Bananas", ShippingTime = "3_Days" };
                var l = new MyClass { Id = 12, Zone = "WEST", Product = "Bananas", ShippingTime = "5_Days" };
                var m = new MyClass { Id = 13, Zone = "WEST", Product = "Bananas", ShippingTime = "5_Days" };
                var myList = new List<MyClass>();
                myList.AddRange(new[] {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m});

                var sublist = (from ee in myList
                                                from ff in myList
                                                where ee.Product == ff.Product
                                                      && ee.Id != ff.Id
                                                select ee).Distinct();

                var match1 =
                       myList.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(
                           record =>
                           new { PRODUCT = record.Product, SHIPPINGTIME = record.ShippingTime }).Where(z => z.Count() == 1);

                var match2 =
                       myList.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(
                           record =>
                           new { PRODUCT = record.Product, SHIPPINGTIME = record.ShippingTime }).Where(z => z.Count() == 2);

                var match3 =
                       myList.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(
                           record =>
                           new { PRODUCT = record.Product, SHIPPINGTIME = record.ShippingTime }).Where(z => z.Count() == 3);

                var match4 =
                       myList.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(
                           record =>
                           new { PRODUCT = record.Product, SHIPPINGTIME = record.ShippingTime }).Where(z => z.Count() == 4);

                var match5 =
                       myList.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(
                           record =>
                           new { PRODUCT = record.Product, SHIPPINGTIME = record.ShippingTime }).Where(z => z.Count() == 5);

                // Get the total from each of these group where they match, throw the rest out.


                foreach (var entry in sublist)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(entry);

                }

                Assert.That(sublist, Is.Not.Null);
            }
        }
```

// Supporting Class

```
public class MyClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Zone { get; set; }
        public string Product { get; set; }
        public string ShippingTime { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you clear up a bit? You say "to create matching groups where the zones and the products available in each match", but in your example group 1 zones do not match.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't make sense. You really have to clear up your question. Even the stuff below 'Result should be' makes no sense.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned previously, the zone and products will change, but in group 1 the products are the same. The products and the fact that both Zone EAST and South contain them indicate a match. Hope that helps.

Comment: To be clear I need to count the groups of products within the entire list regardless of the zone. Don't look at it like an ordinary sort, it's not. The two rows below the group two example clear fit into group 1 because they only contain bananas and oranges. No apples in zones EAST and SOUTH. Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood you right, but I think you want to do something like that:

```
myList.Select(record => record.Product)
      .Distinct()
      .Select(p => new 
              { 
                  Product = p, 
                  Zones = myList.Where(r => r.Product == p)
                                .Select(r => r.Zone)
                                .Distinct() 
              })
      .GroupBy(an => an.Zones.Count())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you - a person that read the whole question. It does look like what I'm looking for. Let me give this a go.

Comment: aush - Thanks very much! this got me pointed in the write direction.